# How to wrapAll children of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have :

```
<div>
  <a> //this
    <span>sometext<span> //problem
  </a>
  <a></a> //this
  <a></a> //this
  <span>sometext</span> //this
  <div><div>
  <input>
</div>
```

I need to wrap marked elements and get result like this :

```
<div>
  <div> //wrapped
    <a> 
      <span>sometext<span> 
    </a>
    <a></a> 
    <a></a> 
    <span>sometext</span>
  </div> //wrapped
    <div><div>
    <input>

</div>
```

But when i do this with  `$("div a, div span").wrapAll("<div></div>");`
its taking `span` from `a` but I didn't write `div a span`. So I get this :

```
<div>
  <div> //wrapped
    <a>       
    </a>
    <span>sometext<span> //need to be child of tag a
    <a></a> 
    <a></a> 
    <span>sometext</span>
  </div> //wrapped
    <div><div>
    <input>

</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

Comment: You dont have proper start and end tags.... `<span>sometext<span>` as well

Comment: Use the child selector instead of the descendant selector: `$("div > a, div > span")`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

But it will be better to add a class/some other identifier to the container div

```
<div class="someclass">
    <a> //this
        <span>sometext</span> //problem
    </a>
    <a></a> //this
    <a></a> //this
    <span>sometext</span> //this
    <div></div>
    <input />
</div>
```

then

```
$("div.someclass").children("a, span").wrapAll("<div />");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GgE6S/)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this by class: `$(".classname").wrapAll("");` and add the class `classname` to your first `div`